# How to recursively build up a json lens

Tags: scala

I'm using [json-lenses](https://github.com/jrudolph/json-lenses) and trying to recursively search for a branch of a Json object, something akin to:

```
import spray.json._
import spray.json.lenses.JsonLenses._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def getLens(json: JsValue, lensAcc: Lens = Nil, depth: Int = 0): Lens = {
  if (depth > 10) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Recursive search for lens exhausted.")
  }
  val thisLens = lensAcc / 'rec / element(0)
  json.extract[JsObject](thisLens / 'properties.?) match {
    case None => getLens(json, thisLens, depth + 1)
    case _ => thisLens
  }
}

val json = """{"rec": [{"rec": [{"properties": {}}]}]}""".parseJson.asJsObject

val myLens = getLens(json)
```

which isn't quite right. I'm relatively new to Scala and can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: I think the problem comes down to 1) how to specify Lens as a parameter type, and 2) how to specify an empty lens. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
  def nextLens = 'rec / element(0)

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  final def getLens(json: JsObject, lensAcc: Lens[Id] = nextLens, depth: Int = 0): Lens[Id] = {
    if (depth > 10) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Recursive search for lens exhausted.")
    }
    json.extract[JsObject](lensAcc / 'properties.?) match {
      case None => getLens(json, lensAcc / nextLens, depth + 1)
      case _ => lensAcc
    }
  }
```

Test:

```
scala> val json = JsonParser("""{"rec": [{"rec": [{"properties": {}}]}]}""").asJsObject
json: spray.json.JsObject = {"rec":[{"rec":[{"properties":{}}]}]}
scala> getLens(json)
res6: spray.json.lenses.Lens[spray.json.lenses.Id] = spray.json.lenses.JsonLenses$$anon$1@448cd79c
scala> json.extract[JsObject](res6)
res9: spray.json.JsObject = {"properties":{}}
```

I don't know if there is something like an empty lens...